# tcolorbox/minipage: How to automatically set the image height to that of its parent's?

Tags: floats, tcolorbox, minipage

For the following, I need to

1- automatically set each image height to that of the parent `minipage`/`tcolorbox` instead of doing it manually by `height=2cm`

2- understand why `example-image-a` inside the minipage is going over the right margin

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][2cm][c]{\dimexpr\textwidth/3}
        First line\\ Second Line
    \end{minipage}}%
\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][2cm][c]{\dimexpr\textwidth/3}
        \centering Centered Text
    \end{minipage}}%
\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][2cm][c]{\dimexpr\textwidth/3}
        \flushright \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}}%


\vspace{2\baselineskip}

\begin{tcbraster}[
        raster columns=3, raster rows=1,
        raster height = 2cm, sharp corners,
        valign=center,
        raster column skip = 0mm,
        boxrule = 0.5pt, colback = white,
        boxsep=0mm, left=0pt, right=0pt
    ]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[left=0pt,right=0pt]
        First line\\ Second Line
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center]
        Centered Text
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=right]
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add a `%` after `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}`, or write `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\noindent` in that order

Comment: @user94293 Thanks. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to subtract the length of the border: \fboxrule for the left border + \fboxrule for the right border.  The length of a cell is therefore \textwidth/3 - 2\fboxrule

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

% \setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt} % <-- choose the thickness of the border
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\noindent
\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][2cm][c]{\dimexpr\textwidth/3-2\fboxrule\relax}
        First line\\ Second Line
    \end{minipage}}%
\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][2cm][c]{\dimexpr\textwidth/3-2\fboxrule\relax}
        \centering Centered Text
    \end{minipage}}%
\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][2cm][c]{\dimexpr\textwidth/3-2\fboxrule\relax}
        \raggedleft \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```